# How to hide Google Desktop icon on Gnome?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, gnome-panel, google-desktop

It is near the upper left corner. I don't need the icon there. How to hide it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @S B Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop. I use Google Desktop but I don't need the icon to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to hide it without removing the notification area tray from the panel, or simply not using Google Desktop. If you upgrade to 11.04 or 11.10, it is possible to blacklist the icon from the panel.